# Newbie Creating Django models

Tags: django

I'm new to django and trying to understand how I might create my models.  I'm building an app that can be used to create documents from a template.  These documents can be of a number of different types, and contain generic sections as well as sections specific to each document type.  I'm intending for the specific sections that the user can choose from (to include in their document), to change according to the document type they have chosen to create.  Yet the generic sections will be used no matter what the document type.

I'm having a hard time getting my head round how I might build my models to achieve this.  I've considered giving the document model and sections model a document type that can be set and referenced in html, matching the sections to each document:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Sections(models.Model):
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

or adding in a document type model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType)

class Sections(models.Model):
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType)

class DocumentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

But I'm worried that this will cause problems due to many documents sharing some generic sections.  And so I wondered if I separate the generic and specific sections:

```
class GenericSection():
    document_type = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentType)

class SpecificSection():
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType)
```

or even separate each document type into it's own app.  I think I've got myself into a twist with this and would appreciate any feedback on whether there's a more appropriate way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a document can be of only one type, I would personally have that in it's own table.  That way they are not duplicated everywhere.

Then your document table's document type should be a foreign key to the document type table (assuming a document can only have one type or a many to many relation to the document type table if a document can be more than one type)

foreign key's are a great way to make sure your table doesn't turn into a nightmare of pointing to the wrong values or dead values etc...

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  Would then the Section table's document type be a Many to Many relationship to the document type table, so that each section can belong to one or more document types?

Comment: Many to Many only needs to be defined in one model file, so if you want document to have a manytomany for it's documentType field, just define the ManyToMany in your document model file and not the DocumentType model file.   (this assumes you think a document can have multiple documentTypes) if your documents can only have one type, than use a foreign key.  It seems to me you're on the right track with your thought process of using either a foreignkey or a manytomany.